# Cassandra streaming to file using java

Tags: java, file, cassandra, stream, datastax

Is there a way to stream rows out of cassandra, transform them and then write to a file using datastax java driver, without loading everything in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use server-side paging. How ?

```
Statement statement = ...;
statement.setFetchSize(10000); // 10 000 rows for each page
final ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement);
final Iterator<Row> iterator = resultSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = iterator.next();
    // Process the row here
}
```